# Kubernetes ingress "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" vs "ingressClassName"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

My Kubernetes ingress has the following:

```
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations: 
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
      ...
      ...
    # -- Defines which ingress controller will implement the resource
    ingressClassName: ""
```

I'm a bit confused about the difference between "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" and "ingressClassName.".

I believe "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" needs to match the ingressClass as defined in the AWS ALB Ingress Controller.

However, then I'm confused about the role of "ingressClassName"? As that seems to be the same thing.

Any clarity would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, both refer to the same thing, but `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` is deprecated from Kubernetes v1.22+. and `ingressClassName` is introduced in `1.18`, so if you are using higher version you can `ingressClassName`

> Before the `IngressClass` resource and `ingressClassName` field were added in Kubernetes 1.18, Ingress classes were specified with a `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation on the Ingress. This annotation was never formally defined, but was widely supported by Ingress controllers.

> **The newer `ingressClassName` field on Ingresses is a replacement for that annotation**, but is not a direct equivalent. While the annotation was generally used to reference the name of the Ingress controller that should implement the Ingress, **the field is a reference to an IngressClass resource that contains additional Ingress configuration**,

[ingress-deprecated-annotation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation)

Your example is

```
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations: 
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
```

its equivalent value is `className: "nginx"`

```
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    className: "alb" -> ingressClassName
```

if you check the `ingress` template, it will be like this

```
  ingressClassName: {{ .Values.ingress.className }}
```

Answer (score 1):

`kubernetes.io/ingress.class` is deprecated but it still used in GKE

[image]