# Create a kubernetes and add a second ingress-nginx controler but kubernetes didn't recognize how to use the correct controller

Tags: azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I add the second ingress-nginx controller but kubernetes doesn't knpw where to send the traffic between these controllers. Have one way to disable/delete the second nginx and fix everything?

The second istio-nginx controller is created based on [this tutorial](https://devopscube.com/setup-ingress-kubernetes-nginx-controller). The original created using my terraform. At this point I can't delete my cluster; I'm only able to fix it.

How to solve this and next step that I need is create a new ingress-nginx that can be used to another application on same kubernetes cluster.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have two ingress controller and want to route traffic to the correct ingress controller. If so, then in your ingress yaml you can add kubernetes.io/ingress.class annotation or the ingressClassName both are same. So accordingly suppose you want to use the other ingress controller with the class nginx2, you can set the kubernetes.io/ingress.class annotation to nginx2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

To route traffic between two Ingress controllers in an AKS cluster, you need to create multiple Ingress resources, each associated with the appropriate Ingress controller. This is typically achieved by specifying the [ingressClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915526/kubernetes-ingress-kubernetes-io-ingress-class-vs-ingressclassname) field in the Ingress definition.

While deploying the two Ingress controllers in your cluster, ensure that they are using different `ingressClassName` values. You mentioned one is based on Istio-Nginx, and let's say the other is the default Nginx Ingress.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
  - host: app1.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app1-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

and the other one as

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app2-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "istio-nginx"
  rules:
  - host: app2.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app2-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

As you can see `app1-ingress` is associated with the Nginx Ingress controller, and `app2-ingress` is associated with the Istio-Nginx controller.

[image]
[image]

Once done, you can get the external IP of your nginx and istio

[image]

Update your DNS records to point `app1.example.com` to the external IP or DNS of the Nginx Ingress controller, and `app2.example.com` to the external IP or DNS of the Istio-Nginx controller.1.  verify that traffic is correctly routed to the respective Ingress controllers based on the specified hostnames.
Now, you have two Ingress controllers handling traffic for different applications in your AKS cluster.